# internal server error (I followed a toturial to the letter, still I am getting 2 errors)

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopping-cart, web-development-server

```
https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/stripe-checkout-simple/commit/b1bac8e70cf783c983f2d41b7f1e17b0617c324d
```

above is the link to the github where you can see the entire code.
and below I will paste my code in case u dont wanna go to github:
/**server start**/

```
require("dotenv").config()
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const cors = require("cors")
app.use(express.json())
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:5500",
  })
)

const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY)

const storeItems = new Map([
  [1, { priceInCents: 10000, name: "Learn React Today" }],
  [2, { priceInCents: 20000, name: "Learn CSS Today" }],
])

app.post("/create-checkout-session", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      payment_method_types: ["card"],
      mode: "payment",
      line_items: req.body.items.map(item => {
        const storeItem = storeItems.get(item.id)
        return {
          price_data: {
            currency: "usd",
            product_data: {
              name: storeItem.name,
            },
            unit_amount: storeItem.priceInCents,
          },
          quantity: item.quantity,
        }
      }),
      success_url: `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/success.html`,
      cancel_url: `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/cancel.html`,
    })
    res.json({ url: session.url })
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: e.message })
  }
})

app.listen(3000)
    /** script.js start **/
    
        const button = document.querySelector("button")
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/create-checkout-session", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      items: [
        { id: 1, quantity: 3 },
        { id: 2, quantity: 1 },
      ],
    }),
  })
    .then(res => {
      if (res.ok) return res.json()
      return res.json().then(json => Promise.reject(json))
    })
    .then(({ url }) => {
      window.location = url
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.error(e.error)
    })
})
    /*** start of .env **/
CLIENT_URL=http://localhost:5500
STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY:  I have it in my code but wont post it here. 
    
    /*** index.html**/
       <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Checkout</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Errors I am getting are:
1- script.js:3 POST http://localhost:3000/create-checkout-session 500 (Internal Server Error)
2- Even tho I provided my key, double checked it even:
You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY'). See https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication for details, or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/.

Comment: can you atleast add the error as a code snippet? In the question the points are merged

Comment: and its saying that I need to provide a KEY, but I already have my key in the folder

Comment: can you tell me what have you written inside the fetch? did you change the `YOUR_SECRET_KEY` to your stripe private key?

Comment: it is working for me, I tested in my local, it works fine

Comment: you can add STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY in .env and in fetch instead of API_KEY just put you stripe private key (like this Bearer KJhsj.builbrsvbuibuw)

Comment: you should have 2 folders, one client and one server, go to SERVER and then do npm start, and open the index.html using live server

Comment: dude what error are you getting?

Comment: did you do npm i, go inside server and execute thi command

Comment: thats why I have "F:\Web Development\MyElement\server>" when calling start, I am already inside my server

Comment: DO npm i and then npm start

Comment: man just delete what ever you have and then clone the edited repo

Comment: go inside server and then do npm i and npm start, go back to client and open index.html

Comment: dude ADD npm i and after it completes do npm start, add .env file too inside the server folder

Comment: are you new to web developmenr?

Comment: ok server started, however, I am getting this error in my live server: POST http://localhost:3000/create-checkout-session 500 (Internal Server Error) AND You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY'). See https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication for details, or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/.

Comment: WHAT DID YOU ADD INSIDE fetch?

Comment: add the image of the console error

Comment: the website doesnt let me add images, I have to be over level 10

Comment: what did you name your .env variable?

Comment: do you have a .env file?

Comment: I am pasting the KEY directly do the authorization, so I dont have a KEY  in my .env, but I have the file

Comment: dude ADD A KEY INSIDE .env you are referencing it on server.js file when you are importin stripe

Comment: YOU SHOULD NOT ADD keys like object just copy this and add in your env 
`STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY=sk_test_51JVtjcACtK5pBXsPyesrdG1V8YPQVBRV6SMMZ45RszLhD0KJTeAkuHDuFeT6AYM`

Comment: did it, nothing is working, same errors

Comment: here you go, no gitignore at all, I deleted everything in it, here is the complete code I have right now with my private key https://github.com/LouaiAlaranji/not-working-website

Comment: where are the client and server folders?

Comment: I couldnt upload a folder, so I uploaded the files inside of them, just put them in folders when u clone them

Comment: I am sorry I can't help you, I tried my best explainig you for 3 hours, it looks like you don't know javascript and you are totally new to programming, I suggest that you learn javascript and then start following all these fancy tutorials, it will get you no where in programming if you just follow videos blindly. My answer below is absolutely correct.

Comment: thank you so much for your time, sorry for taking this long, I will try again tomorrow and see if I come somewhere.

Comment: did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The error clearly states that

**You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY')**

so in script.js file when you are doing fetch change the fetch like this,

Note: script.js runs **client side** so you **won't have access to process.env**

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/create-checkout-session", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization" : 'Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY' //? FIX Replace the scret key 
                                                //?with your stripe secret key
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      items: [
        { id: 1, quantity: 3 },
        { id: 2, quantity: 1 },
      ],
    }),
  })
    .then(res => {
      if (res.ok) return res.json()
      return res.json().then(json => Promise.reject(json))
    })
    .then(({ url }) => {
      window.location = url
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.error(e.error)
    })
```